# SwipeRefreshLayout with ViewPager

Tags: java, android, swiperefreshlayout

I'm trying to implement swipe refresh on my app but as i am new to java I'm a bit lost about where i should put what

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager_fragments"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/ad_banner_container"
            android:layout_below="@id/tabs">

        </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

so you can see my xlm code for the swipe refresh and also here is my main activity code for the same, can anyone tell me what to put here

```
mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
                new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {
                        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onRefresh called from SwipeRefreshLayout");

                        // This method performs the actual data-refresh operation.
                        // The method calls setRefreshing(false) when it's finished.
                        myUpdateOperation();
                    }
                }
        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ref : [Journal Dev Article on Swipe Refresh](https://www.journaldev.com/10708/android-swiperefreshlayout-pull-swipe-refresh)

```
    mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
                    new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onRefresh() {
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onRefresh called from SwipeRefreshLayout");
                    shuffle(); // the function that populates your view 
                    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                            myUpdateOperation();
                        }
                    }
            );
```

The shuffle can be a function like

```
public void shuffle(){
        Collections.shuffle(arrayList, new Random(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```